# Only displaying the outer border of a number of features - OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have a OpenLayers-3 map that visualises dynamically generated content.
Among other things it displays certain areas that share a certain variable. The layer itself is provided as a wfs-Layer (geojson from geoserver).

Currenty it looks like this:
[image]

However, I'd like it to be displayed slightly different. Instead of every single feature being diplayed with a frame, I want only the outer border to be displayed. I think I'd need something like a bounding box fitted to the geometry of the features.
Merging the features would also be an alternative, however, since the features are generated dynamically there is no way of pre-displayed merging. It would have to be realised on the fly.

I should also mention that not all features necessarily have to be neighbours.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need a bounding box or a convex hull?

Comment: Convex hull. That keyword itself is already pretty useful.

Comment: If I had to that I think I'd have the convex hull be calculated on the server. And if I used GeoServer I'd create a PostGIS layer that uses a DB view that calculates that convex hull.